# What is an alternative word to the phrase "In the case of"

Tags: alternatives

I found the following sentence in one of my dictionaries.

> The amount of fruit in fruit juices must be 6% **in the case of** berries
>   and 10% **in the case of** other fruits.

I would like to know a simple word that can be used instead of "in the case of" in the sentence above. As far as I searched, "for" can be used, but "for" has a lot of meanings, so I would like to know whether there is a more suitable word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ***for*** is the best word to use, and I actually can't think of other suitable alternatives. Although ***for*** does have many meanings, it is pretty clear what you're trying to say in this sentence.

***In the case of*** is perfectly fine, too. If the writing is technical in nature (it looks like it could be), ***in the case of*** might be more appropriate, because it is a little more precise. Otherwise, I think ***for*** is suitable for other types of communication.